# How to rename Dogmeat?

Tags: fallout-3

That poor dog has already lost his master, can he at least keep his dignity? A console command would be preferred over having to use a mod.

Comment: What will you name him? Catnip?

Comment: @hammythepig [Fluffy](http://harrypotter.wikia.com/wiki/Fluffy) :-P

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I realize you said "no mods" but what about making one yourself?

You could use the GECK: http://fallout.bethsoft.com/eng/downloads/geck.php

There is a way to edit attributes of NPCs: http://geck.bethsoft.com/index.php/Category:NPC

Then you would save your mod as an ESP and it wouldn't break achievements.

Comment: Thanks, that's the way I finally did it. With some more effort I could even change the Dialogue options to replace the hard-coded "Dogmeat" there

Comment: This is great. I'm going to rename him 'Pedigree Chum'.

Comment: @AlanB What have I done?!

Answer (score 2):

Here is how you do it with the console:

Open it up, click on Dog Meat to make sure he's selected, then type in:

> setactorfullname "new name"

Note, opening the console will prevent you from earning any achievements for that session.  You'll have to save the game and then exit the game and go back in to continue to earn achievements.

Comment: Bah, who needs achievements anyway :-7 But I get a `SCRIPTS: Script 'SysWindowCompileAndRun', line1: Item 'new name' not found for parameter Message. Compiled script not saved!` :-(

Comment: @Zommuter do you have dogmeat selected when you run the command?  If not then it won't know what item to set the name on.

Comment: At the fifth attempt I managed to actually select dogmeat instead of the background, but it's still the same error :-/

Comment: Hm, according to [this thread](http://www.gamefaqs.com/boards/918428-fallout-3/47971531) the parameter to `setactorfullname` is not a string but a message (MESG), so now to figure out how to create a message - try and google that :-/

Comment: @Zommuter :/  that makes it complicated.  You might want to try the FOSE solution in that thread then, probably easier than constructing a message.

Comment: Probably, but the next page states that the FOSE solution is only temporal until one reloads...

Comment: Ok, I used GECK, which was the work of a minute. Weird though that this console command has this strange syntax...